# Does forcing a type into a variable make the whole statement into the inserted type?

Tags: java, variables, types, type-conversion, var

I am at a dilemma as to whether the type double would change the variable of `width` into a double or only `length` :

```
double ratio = (double) length / width;
```

Comment: While this does in fact contain a _statement_, the important part is the _expressions_, and there are four: `length`, `width`, the quotient of those, and the value of the assignment to `ratio` (the same as the quotient). What is relevant is the type of each of these expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****Type of the variables length and width do not change after executing that line.** The type you have given to those variables when you declare them, remains as it is.** Assuming width and length is type int, I wrote the small program below to check the type.

```
public class CheckType{

    void printType(int x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is an int");
    }

    void printType(double x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is an double");
    }
    
    public static void main(String []args){
         int length=6; int width=2;
         double ratio = (double) length / width;
         CheckType x = new CheckType();
         
         System.out.println(length);
         System.out.println(width);
         x.printType(ratio);
         x.printType(length);
         x.printType(width);

     }
}
```

Output from the above program is:

```
6
2
3.0 is an double
6 is an int
2 is an int
```

Answer (score 0):

It effectively changes both.

Your expression, `(double) length / width`, is equivalent to `((double) length) / width`. However the Java language does not define dividing a `double` by a value of a different type than `double`. Therefore `width` is implicitly *promoted* to a double before the division is performed.

Personally I sometimes write such an expression as `(double) length / (double) width` to make it clearer what happens. It’s a practice I haven’t seen elsewhere, and I am sure that a lot of programmers will just find my code needlessly long.

What really happens behind the scenes, I don’t know, and we should not care. If some JVM has a way of performing a division of a `double` by, say, an `int`, it may use it as long as it *guarantees to give the same result as if `width` had been converted to `double`*. The language specifies the *result* of our code, not the *implementation*.

Nishadi Wickramanayaka is correct in the other answer: the variables themselves are unchanged. Neither the variable `length` nor `width` change their types. Only values taken from the variables are converted to `double` for use in the calculation.